# is there memory leak when STL throws a "bad_alloc" exception?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stl

I have a program that using STL to use big containers of numbers, sometimes `vector`, sometimes `deque`; sometimes it constructing a big `vector` directly, sometimes it starts with a small size then enlarges using `resize`.

The `vector` or `deque` constructor or `resize` sometimes throws a "bad_alloc" exception. My question is, is there memory leak here? 
If there's no memory leak, I might still continue; but if there is , things are more troublesome.

My system is Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2013, and working on 32-bit programs.

Comment: FYI: http://stroustrup.com/except.pdf

Comment: @NickyC what's your point?

Comment: @PaulRooney yeah it's running out of memory, but I assume during `constructor` or `resize` of STL containers, `new` or `malloc` is used, so when `bad_alloc` is thrown from STL, did STL clean up the memory part? is there memory leak?

Comment: @athos The primary example in that paper is how STL `vector` not leak memory when exception is thrown.

Comment: @NickyC great to know that, thanks for the summary!

Comment: "is there memory leak here?" You can check that with memory leak detection tools such as valgrind.

Comment: "If there's no memory leak, I might still continue" It will be hard to do anything useful after a `bad_alloc`.

Comment: @Juanchopanza: Depends how big the chunk of memory was you tried to allocate.

Comment: Re: " returns "bad_alloc" exception" -- get in the habit of describing actions correctly. The code does **not** return an exception, it **throws** an exception. There's a big difference between 'return' and 'throw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

A thrown `std::bad_alloc` exception does not mean there is a memory leak.    It means that dynamic allocation using operator `new` or operator `new[]` has failed.

Default allocators used by the standard container types (`std::Vector`, `std::list`, etc) typically use operator `new` or `new[]`, so can also throw a `std::bad_alloc` if they fail.

A memory leak is just one possible cause of memory exhaustion and, in turn, memory exhaustion is only one possible cause of  a failure to dynamically allocate memory using `new` or `new[]`.

Generally speaking, if `std::bad_alloc` is thrown, it means an attempt to allocate memory has failed (and does not need to be deallocated).  So there is no leak.     If some object (or class) is poorly implemented, it might cause a memory leak if an exception is thrown.   The standard describes requirements of the standard containers that prevent that, assuming the elements of the vector also provide suitable guarantees.

Comment: A poorly designed new operator could leak memory. Imagine a new operator that created a `new` Object and a `new` log entry, the second call to new could fail, leaking the first object. I admit I think this irrelevant to OP, but perhaps useful to someone else.

Comment: @Zekian - Not so.    When an allocation fails, a `new` expression is not required to release objects that have previously been successfully allocated.   It is up to the caller to keep track of those objects, and to release them using an appropriate `delete` expression.

Comment: My statement is a warning to those who a custom implement new.

Answer (score 0):

`std::bad_alloc` is thrown when `new` or `new[]` fails to allocate memory.

You may have run out of main memory? You may have have tried to allocate a particularly structure `new int[1024*1024*1024];`? Your heap may have become fragmented (Many allocations and deletions), So a continuous space of memory of the size that you want couldn't be allocated.